# Custom sorting strings in c++

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I'm having a bit of an issue with custom sorting strings. What I basically have is an `std::list` of `std::pair`, whose elements are `enum class` and `std::string`. *Enum* is for colours (those do sort correctly) and *strings* contain numbers in [2, 10] interval, with additions of letters J, Q, K and A, respectively. As you may have already guessed, it's a deck of cards, that must look like this after sorting:
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A.

What should my lambda function look like in order to achieve this? Or is there another way?

This is what I've compe up with so far:

```
enum class Colours
{
Spades, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds
};

typedef std::list<std::pair<Colours, std::string>> Deck;
typedef std::pair<Boje, std::string> Pair;
```

And here's the actual sorting:

```
deck.sort( [] (const Pair &x, const Pair &y) -> bool {
        if(x.first == y.first) return x.second < y.second;
        else return x.first < y.first;
    } );
```

And the current sorting result: 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A J K Q

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to provide the results, it's edited. 10 comes before 2, and letters are A J K Q, but need to be J Q K A.

Comment: it's normal to use an enum for the card faces also, with a conversion function to convert to strings when needed

Comment: I would suggest creating an array/list with the correct order, try to grab the index of the two elements and compare the indices

Comment: can the issue be that you are comparing character instead of strings

Comment: just use char instead of std::string and it should work.

Comment: It's an assignment, I'm not allowed to use side-containers, and `std::pair` members must remain as they are (that is `enum class` and `std::string`).

Comment: @scrapper that worked like a charm, thanks. Write it as an aswer and I'll  mark it best. Thanks!

Comment: @scrapper how are you converting the string `10` to a char?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I used `c_str()`

Comment: what's odd is, that it works fine on c9, but fails to sort correctly in Visual Studio.

Comment: Because it is wrong. You are not comparing the value 10, best case you are comparing the value of 1, worst case you are comparing the value of a char*

Comment: @FantasticMrFox how should I do it then? Any suggestions?

Comment: @MelvinBrooks The 2 answers below are both good.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox sorry missed that. Yout could try to save the 2-10 values as decimal in char, but the solutions already presented are better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing `string`s, that is, you compare them in alphabetical order. Let's see which comparisons will yield bad results:

> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 vs. 10
>
> J vs A
>
> Q vs K
>
> K vs A

So you will need to write your comparison to check whether any of the values is 10, A or J. If it is 10, check whether the other is a number. If it is A, check whether the other is J or K. If it is K, check whether the other is Q or A. If any of those cases are met, then return the logical value which corresponds to your needs. Otherwise work as you did before:

```
deck.sort( [] (const Pair &x, const Pair &y) -> bool {
        if(x.first == y.first) {
            //Here you need to implement your custom cases as described above
            return x.second < y.second;
        }
        else return x.first < y.first;
    } );
```

Comment: This is what I eventually ended up doing. I did have to write a whole bunch of ifs, but it works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One thing you have going for you is that the first character of each `string` is unique.  This code is untested, but it should be close:

```
unsigned int face_value(std::string const &face) {
    if(std::isdigit(face[0])) {
        // if the length is 1 we just need the digit
        if(face.length() == 1) {
            return face[0] - '0';
        }
        // if it's not 1, it has to be 10
        return 10;
    }
    switch(face[0]) {
    case 'J':
        return 11;
        break;

    case 'Q':
        return 12;
        break;

    case 'K':
        return 13;
        break;

    case 'A':
        return 14;
        break;

    default:
        assert(false);
        break;
    }
}

bool face_compare(std::string const &first, std::string const &second) {
    return face_value(first) < face_value(second);
}
```

With the helper functions, the lambda is trivial:

```
deck.sort( [] (const Pair &x, const Pair &y) -> bool {
    return std::tie(x.first, face_value(x.second)) <
           std::tie(y.first, face_value(y.second));
});
```

As a side note, my guess is that you want to compare face values before `Colour`s, but I'm sticking with your original logic for now.

Comment: I'd express it as `return std::tie(x.first, face_value(x.second)) < std::tie(y.first, face_value(y.second))`

Comment: @Caleth - Honestly didn't know `tuple`s supported the boolean operators.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You can have a lookup of the face values of your cards, expressed as a `std::map<std::string, int>`. Rather than explicitly specifying the less than of two values, we can use the `std::tuple` less than, with `std::tie`.

```
// throws std::out_of_range if not passed a valid face
int face_value (const std::string & face)
{
    static const std::map<std::string, int> faces {
        { "2", 2 },  { "3", 3 },  { "4", 4 },
        { "5", 5 },  { "6", 6 },  { "7", 7 },
        { "8", 8 },  { "9", 9 },  { "10", 10 },
        { "J", 11 }, { "Q", 12 }, { "K", 13 },
        { "A", 14 },
    }

    return faces.at( face );
}

deck.sort( [] (const Pair &x, const Pair &y) -> bool {
    return std::tie(x.first, face_value(x.second)) < std::tie(y.first, face_value(y.second));
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not sorting the way you want because `10` is less than `2` because `1` is less than `2`. You might be better off using a class and a comparison operator:

```
struct Card {
    enum class Suite { Spades, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds};

    operator<(const Card& other) {
        if (suite == other.suite) { return number < other.number; }
        return suite < other.suite;
    }

    string toString(); // Function to make your card string representation.

    private:
       int number; // 2 - 14 (11, 12, 13, 14: J, Q, K, A)
       Suite suite;
}
```

Then you could do:

```
std::list<Card> myList;
myList.sort();
```

**Note**: Untested code, also needs appropriate constructors converters etc.

Comment: That would be great, but defining operators and using classes is not allowed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How about enums for suit and value:

```
enum class Suit {
    Spades, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds
};

enum class Val {
    v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, vJ, vQ, vK, vA
};

typedef std::pair<Suit, Val> Pair;
```

Then, if you want it, a method to print a `Pair`:

```
std::string GetCardName(Pair p)
{
    std::string suit_name;
    switch (p.first)
    {
        case Suit::Spades : suit_name = "Spades"; break;
        /* ... */
        case Suit::Diamonds : suit_name = "Diamonds"; break;
    }

    std::string val_name;
    switch (p.second)
    {
        case Val::v2 : val_name = "2"; break;
        case Val::v3 : val_name = "3"; break;
        /* ... */
        case Val::vA : val_name = "Ace"; break;
    }

    return val_name + " of " + suit_name;
}
```

Then you can compare exactly as you originally wrote, since the Suit and Val enums are implicitly ordered:

```
std::list<Pair> Deck =
{
    std::make_pair(Suit::Spades, Val::vA),
    std::make_pair(Suit::Clubs, Val::v7)
};

Deck.sort( [](const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2)
{
    if(p1.first == p2.first) return p1.second < p2.second;
    else return p1.first < p2.first;
} );

for (const auto& pair : Deck)
{
    std::cout << GetCardName(pair) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Ace of Spades
7 of Clubs
```

Here is a [minimal working example](https://godbolt.org/g/pyaeaw) of the whole thing.